# Arrow pointing to a particular position in a vector

Tags: latex

I would like to point an arrow to particular position in a vector and have text label the arrow.  For instance,

```
  [1 2 3 4 5 6 ]

         |
      position 4
```

Where the vertical bar is replaced by an up arrow that actually points to position 4.  I tried this using eqnarray, but that messed up the spacing in the vector.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! First: [*avoid eqnarray!*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/49683) Also, to have a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) (or [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) from you would help understanding your specific need.

That said, improvising I got this minimal code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
[1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6]\\
 & & & $\downarrow$ & & \\
\multicolumn{6}{r}{position 4}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output:

[image]